# After using CNAME to redirect URL, Webfonts no longer work

Tags: webfonts, cname, google-webfonts

Running in chrome:
[www.AshGavs.com](http://www.ashgavs.com)
vs.
http://ashgavs.cloudant.com/site/_design/AshGavsCouch/main/index.html

Really confusing, especially because the fonts are hosted on google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh. Cross domain error. I had simply listed "/fonts.css" for my fonts file, so I think it was going to "AshGavs.com/fonts.css" for the file.